# How to get different backgrounds in a container?

Tags: html, css

I'm actually working on PHP storm. I would like to add a different background color to the container-fluid when the website page gets smaller. The color is taken by an advanced custom field (in this case Color Selector) from WordPress.

I'm new to HTML...I tried creating a row and then a column with the

```
class="col-12 col-lg-6 col d-block d-lg-none"
```

and another column with the

```
class="col-12 col-lg-6 col d-block d-lg-none"
```

and it works but that is not what I need

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:600px; background- 
image:url('{!! get_field('head_image2')['url'] !!}'); background- 
repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center 
top;" >
</div>
```

I except that when the page is narrowed for mobiles the background color changes.

Comment: Can you do all this in CSS? Ideally you would want to do it there using media queries. Much more easier and it's not inlined (inlined CSS is not best practice)

Answer (score 0):

If you drop these in a `<style>` tag they should do the job:

```
.container-fluid {
  background-image: url('path-to-small-image.jpg');
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid {
    background-image: url('path-to-larger-image.jpg');
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container-fluid {
    background-image: url('path-to-very-large-image.jpg');
  }
}
```

The above targets your `div` and dynamically changes the background image depending on the screen resolution. It's done using regular **CSS** and can be simplified by using a preprocessor scripting language like **SASS** or **LESS**